# Why is "Software X doesn't" a valid answer to "What software has option Y?"?

Tags: support, answers

Software recommendation questions are crap, but occasionally useful. While looking for a [Text editor to open big (giant, huge, large) text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files), I came across this strange answer:

> My normal standby is Notepad++, but in this case I have to post specifically to recommend against it. It can handle reasonably large files okay in most cases, but it really struggles with large XML data.
>
> Something else worth noting: many so-called text editors will treat XML as more than just text. They'll do validation, folding, and try to create a DOM, resulting in a memory image much larger than the file itself.
>
> Notepad++ is doing something like this, but other editors may do it as well.

As there is an infinite choice of software, I think answers which are just "Not X" are useless, as there could be a million of them naming every program anyone has ever made. So I flagged it as not an answer, which a moderator declined.

Why is this a valid answer despite it not answering the question?

Comment: That question cries for being either histo-locked or getting the missing delete-votes.

Comment: *cringes at the atrocity which is that question* - But a lot of those answer could stand to be deleted. Because they provide absolutely no information, or repeat other answers above. Problem is, that question **sucks**, and I don't think there's a moderator that really cares to clean it up, because it will still suck.

Comment: Granted; it would be possibly be a good fit for Software Recommendations SE. Agree that "Not X" is a *terrible* answer, but it **is** an attempted answer.

Comment: An "Other" flag with an explanation was probably called for here. "Not an answer" doesn't really convey what specifically was wrong with that answer. I declined that flag, but I definitely agree with you now that I see more context.

Comment: If someone asked a question like "what's the best place for a short-term loan?", an answer like "Whatever you end up choosing to do, don't go to one of those payday loan places" actually DOES convey useful information, even though it isn't a direct answer to the question being asked.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is completely useless. Such an answer could potentially save research time looking at dead ends.

Comment: [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) might be a good home for a cleaned up version of this question (I think it would be pragmatic to infer a *few* details from the popularity of answers). I'd be willing to clean up the question so it would fit their guidelines, but strictly speaking I wouldn't be able to fix most of the answers as I don't have experience in most of the tools. What do you guys think? Or should I ask on SoftRecs meta? Then again, instead of migrating the question itself, plainly re-asking it there may also be beneficial to "reset" history...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NAA is there for answers that don't *attempt* to answer the question.  It's not appropriate for answers that attempt to, but fail, to answer the question.  If you think that an answer fails to adequately answer the question then the appropriate course of action is to downvote it.

Comment: I think we just had a disagreement on what an attempt is, as  Bill the Lizard♦ said in his comment, I probably should have gone with a custom flag, so I'll accept this answer.